# how to give only access to custom post type for a particular user

Tags: php, wordpress, arguments, roles, wordpress-capabilities

In my code i have a custom post type job.I created a role called job manager.Now i want to give permissions to add,edit ,delete a job for job manager.Only he can access job post type.hoe w to achieve this....

I tried to create job manager  role by following  code

```
          function add_job_manager_role(){
           add_role(
                'job_manager',
                 'Job Manager',
                   array(
                    'read'          => true,
                    'edit_posts'    => false,
                    'delete_posts'  => false,
                    'publish_posts' => false,
                    'upload_files'  => true
           )
        );
     }
   add_action( 'admin_init', 'add_job_manager_role', 4 );
```

how to give permissions to job manager to add ,delete,edit custom post type job

any help greatly appreciated .Thanks in advance ....

Comment: You have already added a role - So Give him capabilities to edit that post type, and put those capabilities into the registration of the post type as well..

Comment: basically : follow this guide : https://3.7designs.co/blog/2014/08/restricting-access-to-custom-post-types-using-roles-in-wordpress/

Comment: Also, If you want to manage role easily you can use members plugin which is just about what you want. https://fr.wordpress.org/plugins/members/

Comment: i already have post type job .i want to give permissions to that post type only.still have to register post type?

Comment: i did not get from using above code. i want  job manager only can add ,edit ,delete job post type how to do this

Comment: @Bala please see my answer with edit.

Answer (score 3):

When you add the role you have to add the capabilities also like so :

```
/**
add CPT capabilites to Role
*/
add_action('admin_init','o99_add_role_caps',999);

function o99_add_role_caps() {

    $role = get_role('my_role');      // ex. job_manager         
    $role->add_cap( 'read_my_CPT');
    $role->add_cap( 'edit_my_CPT' );
    $role->add_cap( 'edit_my_CPT' );
    $role->add_cap( 'edit_other_my_CPT' );
    $role->add_cap( 'edit_published_my_CPT' );
    $role->add_cap( 'publish_my_CPT' );
    $role->add_cap( 'read_private_my_CPT' );
    $role->add_cap( 'delete_my_CPT' );


}
```

`my_CPT` is of course your Custom Post Type when in creating you gave the capabilities arguments or modifying it you did something like :

```
function change_capabilities_of_CPT( $args, $post_type ){

 // Do not filter any other post type
 if ( 'my_CPT' !== $post_type ) { // my_CPT == Custom Post Type == 'job' or other

     // if other post_types return original arguments
     return $args;

 }


// This is the important part of the capabilities 
/// which you can also do on creation ( and not by filtering like in this example )


 // Change the capabilities of my_CPT post_type
 $args['capabilities'] = array(
            'edit_post' => 'edit_my_CPT',
            'edit_posts' => 'edit_my_CPT',
            'edit_others_posts' => 'edit_other_my_CPT',
            'publish_posts' => 'publish_my_CPT',
            'read_post' => 'read_my_CPT ',
            'read_private_posts' => 'read_private_my_CPT',
            'delete_post' => 'delete_my_CPT'
        );

  // Return the new arguments
  return $args;

}
```

Edit I

For further info :

In order to be able to control the CPT, there are several other `capabilities` involved for each operation.

Just for example in order to `publish_my_CPT` and in order to edit you will need the `edit_my_CPT` && `edit_other_my_CPT` && `read_my_CPT` && `read_private_my_CPT` and so on. please look at [capabilities in the Codex](https://wordpress.org/support/article/roles-and-capabilities/) and with the code posted you can add the `_my_CPT` (e.g. - `_job` or whatever CPT ) to those capabilities thus allowing you to achieve he desired result.

Comment: i did not get from using above code. i want  job manager only can add ,edit ,delete job post type how to do this

Comment: In the code posted you have all the permissions, you can always filter the ones you want to. you need to understand that `add` for example is `publish` and `read` for sure you need also.

Comment: i have using same code pattern to get this done but unable to do so,  https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/402045/allowing-custom-user-role-to-access-custom-post-type-in-wordpress-admin can anyone guide?